# How to save shared_ptr result?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

If the result of call `fn()` is `const std::shared_ptr<SomeType>`, what is the best type for client to save the result as?

ie:

```
auto result = fn();

m_myResult = result.get() //or something
```

What type should `m_myResult` be? 
`SomeType *` ? 
or `SomeType`? 
or `shared_ptr<SomeType>` ?

Comment: Ask yourself why the function is returning a shared pointer.

Comment: Why not `std::shared_ptr<SomeType>`?

Comment: [shared_ptr::get](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/get) returns `T*`.

Comment: @mch I don't think OP is set on using `result.get()` but rather is proposing it to find out if it's a workable solution.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux It is an answer to all the questions in the last line. Nevertheless I wrote it as a comment, not an answer ;)

Comment: I don't know why the function is returning a shared_ptr. I don't understand shared_ptrs and have never used them before. Didn't need them 20 years ago.

Comment: @user5773369 You shouldn't look at `std::shared_ptr` as a new burden. It's great new feature designed to make your life easier. It's simply an object that will manage the life time of the result. Use it as any other pointer and you don't have to worry about deleting it.

Comment: Ok; sounds like typical practice would have `m_myResult` be of type `std::shared_ptr<SomeType>` ... right?

Comment: @user5773369 Yes.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, disagree. One needs to understand implications of `shared_ptr`.

Comment: Will `m_myResult` live longer than `result`? Yes, no or don't know?

Comment: Yes, it will live longer as a cached value. Also I need to be able to pass it around...is it bad to pass a shared_ptr as an argument? I'm lost.

Comment: @user5773369 It is OK to pass a `shared_ptr` as an argument but normally you don't need to. Normally the caller can hold the `shared_ptr` to keep the resource alive and you can pass a normal reference or pointer to a function. That way the function can be agnostic to your choice of smart pointer. You only need to pass a `shared_ptr` if you want to transfer ownership. See https://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters/.

Answer (score 2):

A [`shared_ptr<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) is used to express shared ownership of a memory resource. All (appropriately created) `shared_ptr<>`s pointing to the same object share its ownership: the object is deleted only when the last `shared_ptr<>` pointing to it is destroyed (or is `reset()`, see below). Thus, if you would

```
auto raw_ptr = fn().get(); // call shared_ptr<>::get(); DON'T DO THAT
raw_ptr->member_func();    // may crash
```

then the `shared_ptr<>` returned from `fn()` is immediately destroyed and the pointed to object may be too, or it may be destroyed anytime later. In this case, `raw_ptr` will become a [dangling pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer). To avoid that, you must keep ownership by keeping a `shared_ptr<>` object alive:

```
auto ptr = fn();          // move shared_ptr<>: pass ownership
ptr->member_func();       // fine (unless fn() returned an empty pointer)
```

Now the object managed by `ptr` will not be deleted before `ptr` itself is, unless you explicitly [`reset()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/reset) it:

```
ptr.reset();              // removes ownership from ptr
```